# Node/Express/Mongo: How do I render HTML attributes from dynamic content?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, haml, express, pug

I have made a simple blog using Node/Express/Mongo/Jade (and/or HAML.js). I used (and slightly updated) the blog app from this [tutorial](http://eberfreitas.virb.com/blog/text/12619617/), which itself an update of one from [howtonode.org](http://howtonode.org)

I can render attributes such as links, etc., with the template engine just fine, but when I pass data from the db, none of the html renders. I get plain text print-outs of the HTML. I figure I need some other node packages/modules to render the 'dynamic' content, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: The blog you've linked to does not resolve. You've listed a _very_ specific set of technologies that quite new. (most of these are less than 2 years old) Your best bet for this type of question may be the express groups: http://groups.google.com/group/express-js

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted code samples. In jade, when you're passing content you DON'T want to be escaped, be sure you pass it along as `!=` instead of `=` BE EXTREMELY CAREFUL THOUGH! If you don't manually parse out the bad stuff, you could make your website extremely vulnerable.

Answer (score 3):

In jade, when you're passing content you DON'T want to be escaped, be sure you pass it along as `!=` instead of `=`

BE EXTREMELY CAREFUL THOUGH! If you don't manually parse out the bad stuff, you could make your website extremely vulnerable.

You can read some more jade documentation [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/)